# Converting colored .Tiff images to Shapefiles using ArcScan?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vectorization, arcscan

I have a digital map of water pipelines (water lines in various colors, parcel data in black). I want to convert the .tiff image's water pipelines (not parcels) to a shapefile. I have the .tiff geo referenced and but cannot seem to figure out how to get it to work in Arcscan.

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/arcscan-tutorial.pdf

Comment: There is another tool - RasterToPolyline.

Answer (score 1):

You have a multi-coloured image, so you need to isolate just two colors from it before you can vectorize it with ArcScan.

From [Getting started with ArcScan](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/what-is-arcscan-.htm#GUID-D2E9A8EC-CC90-4796-842D-245B6C3747DF):

> ArcScan can vectorize any raster format supported by ArcGIS so long as
>   it is represented as a bi-level image. This requires that you
>   symbolize raster layers with two unique colors. You can use either the
>   ArcMap Unique Values or Classified rendering options to separate the
>   raster into two colors.